# Searching Open Source tool to load raster data into Oracle spatial

Tags: raster, open-source-gis, oracle-spatial, loading

I'm looking for a tool to load raster data into oracle spatial.
I found several commercial products but no open source tool.

Is there anything available in the open source world?

Comment: Oracle Documentation refers to GDAL http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28398/geor_operations.htm#autoId6

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I checked it, GDAL is used to prepare the data so it can then be loaded by an Oracle Java programm. - I hoped for a tool with an UI...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also been looking for a software to test Oracle Spatial GeoRaster. I have found this solution from PCI Geomatics, which is not open source, but, at least it's free.

You can check it here (registration needed):

http://testing.pcigeomatics.com/Forms/RequestGeoRasterLoader.php

I have registered myself and received a download link. However, I am having problems to download the file, so I have contacted the company.

Please, let me know how it goes.

EDIT 1

Talking with the people of PCI Geomatics I found that GeoRaster Loader is no more available. You can download FreeView, which can be connected to Oracle.

EDIT 2

It seems that geotiffs can be loaded directly using GDAL:

http://www.gdal.org/frmt_georaster.html

I will check this too.

EDIT 3

A brief explanation on how to build GDAL with Oracle and GeoRaster support:

https://forums.oracle.com/message/9434691#9434691

Answer (score 1):

GDAL is your best bet if you are looking for an open source solution. It only provides library functions and command line tools, but Oracle also distributes a simple GUI-based ETL that uses GDAL internally.

This tool comes with Oracle Database 12c, but you can also download it in isolation from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/samplecode/spatial-1433316.html

EDIT: I should clarify that the tool embeds a pre-built copy of GDAL 1.10 for win32, win64 and linux-64, but you can use your own copy if you prefer.

Albert